# Publishing scoped npm package for free?

Tags: npm, npm-publish

Am I correct that publishing a scoped npm package (`@foo/bar`), even as `--access=public`, is not free?

It results in a `Failed PUT 404` (or `402`) error. Is this because one needs a (paid) npm organization `@foo`?

**Update** (Mar '17): Npm organisations are [now free](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/158718200065/announcing-free-orgs)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, because to publish a module with scope `@foo` you need an organization named `@foo`. So the scope is defined by having created an organization of the same name, and organizations per se are not free.

Basically the rules are:

- If you want to publish a package for free, don't scope it.
- If you want to scope a package, you have to pay for it.

Comment: As of 2017-03-22 public orgs are free http://blog.npmjs.org/post/158718200065/announcing-free-orgs

Answer (score -3):

You can publish a scoped package for free if you are logged in to npm as user 'foo'.

Comment: What is the password then? :)

Comment: Anyway I've just tried, attempting to publish to under @myuser still results in `Failed PUT 402 You need a paid account to perform this action. For more info, visit: https://www.npmjs.com/private-modules`